# What is the security impact of JavaScript minification?

Tags: javascript, websites, web

In recent years the use of JavaScript minification for web applications proliferated so quickly that it can be considered as a defacto standard nowadays. I am wondering whether the use of such tools is likely to introduce new vulnerabilities not present in the initial source code?

Comment: Security impact #1: Someone appends a browser hook after/in the middle of a valid JS file, and nobody bothers to look for, or investigate it. :)

Comment: @MarkBuffalo didn’t my answer include that?;)

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I didn't look, sorry. :X

Comment: you can get bugs if you don't follow the code style guidelines issues by the minifier, but there's not really any exploits that are based on such mis-translations because js code should be assumed unsafe anyway, and none of the "bugs" are things that could allow unexpected string injection, xss, or drive-by downloads.

Answer (score 5):

It is unlikely that simple substitutions introduce new vulnerabilities.

The rules which minification follows are simple and easy to implement and the grammar of the language is fairly easy to parse.

Thus, the minification itself poses no significant additional threats to usage of JavaScript (essentially a method for remote arbitrary code execution) in general.

After a comment from @Armenius, I‘d like to point out that there are [certain edge cases](https://diracdeltas.github.io/blog/backdooring-js/) in which minifiers make assumptions about the (somehow convoluted) typing system of JavaScript that introduces - well - bugs.

This has yet been fixed, but there is of course no proof that there are not more poorly designed minifiers that do things to minify that (ab)use features differently from what the author intended.

Please also note that it depends on what minifier you use - for example, as anecdotal evidence - the switch from gcc to clang have brought back buffer overflows that were „fixed“ by checking if an integer overflowed in an if statement. The standard says the behavior of overflown integers is undefined and gcc used to start them back at minint. Clang was being clever: »if the integer didn’t flow over, it cannot be negative. If it is negative, there must be an overflow. Which consequences are undefined so I‘m optimizing out the whole if statement«

So, yes, there is a small chance that (basically any software so also) minifiers introduce new bugs. However, I’m confident those are rare and easily fixed as the syntax is not as complicated.

Yet, there is an implication that is often overlooked when it comes to minification: whenever scripts are minified, they become essentially unintelligible for humans unless reinflated. Thus, when they are not included from a well known, trusted CDN, they might contain malicious script pieces hidden in an otherwise fine jQuery-implementation, for example.

And introducing such malicious code can very well be done by minifiers. But on the other hand, such tools are usually open source and a hidden crypto-miner in every minimized script will be spotted fairly quickly by the community.

Apart from that, dropping malicious otherwise not obvious code in a minified script after its generation and before its deployment to the users can be a good hiding place - and ongoing minification makes manual security reviews of websites more complicated.

Comment: `It is highly unlikely that simple substitutions introduce new vulnerabilities.` It's not that easy. Minification can have subtle bugs which may allow you to backdoor seemingly safe code. [Have a look at this](https://diracdeltas.github.io/blog/backdooring-js/) for a basic example.

Comment: @Arminius good point. That minifier doesn’t follow the language and makes assumptions that do not hold - which leads to the problem. I‘ll incorporate that in the answer.